# nvm installed node and npm, get npm not found

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

I download the latest lts version of node from nvm (v16.18.0) but I am getting an error `/bin/sh: 1: npm: not found` when I try to run a script with pm2.

`which npm` returns `/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v16.18.0/bin/npm`, I believe the issue can be solved with creating a symlink but nothing is working for me. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: have you try to unistall and re-install npm?

Comment: yes I did try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve it with:

```
sudo ln -s "$(which node)" "/usr/local/bin/node"
sudo ln -s "$(which npm)" "/usr/local/bin/npm"
```